# Keyboard shortcuts to arrange Chrome tabs on Windows?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Scenario:
I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a new tab, but I don't want it as the right-most tab, I want to slide it a few tabs to the left.

Can I do this using just the keyboard or do I have to use the mouse?

I can't see a shortcut here: [Windows keyboard shortcuts - Chrome Help](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=25799).

Something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> would work nicely.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+PageUp/PageDown ? Works on Linux.

Comment: Unfortunately not :( Damn I miss Linux

Comment: @ahilsend, Weird, why would it work on Linux if it doesn't work on Windows?

Comment: @ahilsend I love you

Comment: @ahilsend It also works on **Macs** (as of September 2023). More info in my comment [here](https://superuser.com/questions/629432/keyboard-shortcuts-to-arrange-chrome-tabs-on-windows/1316201#comment2834780_1316201).

Answer (score 70, accepted):

## Current Solution [2019]

There aren't any built-in, but there are extensions that provides this functionality.

**I'm now using this chrome extension (recommended): [Rearrange Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rearrange-tabs/ccnnhhnmpoffieppjjkhdakcoejcpbga)**

You do have to edit the settings by going to `chrome://extensions/shortcuts` and then changing the values as shown in this screen (if you want to match the Linux shortcuts).

[image: How to customise your shortcuts]

Happy days :)

---

#### Legacy extension (2015)

This is the original one (not updated since 2015): [Keyboard Shortcuts to Reorder Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keyboard-shortcuts-to-reo/moigagbiaanpboaflikhdhgdfiifdodd)

**You need to reload all tabs after installing it or it won't work.**

Comment: The extension doesn't work on macOS Sierra though.

Comment: @LarsNyström I just added this: https://github.com/mohnish/rearrange-tabs works nicely on Sierra, and no need to reload your browser

Comment: @MMachinegun Nice, thank you! For new people here, MMachinegun's extension is not the same as the one in slugmandrew's answer. Here's a direct link to MMachinegun's extension in the Chrome Web Store: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rearrange-tabs/ccnnhhnmpoffieppjjkhdakcoejcpbga

Comment: I've downvoted - not because this answer's bad - just that it's old. As of 2018 there is a better solution https://superuser.com/a/1316201/2581

Comment: Except the `ctrl-shift-page-up/down` shortcuts seem to still only work on Linux, and the OP mentioned the Windows keyboard shortcuts help page, so that's presumably what they're looking for.

Comment: Default keyboard shortcuts are:  
**Move selected tab(s) Left:**  Mac(Ctrl+Shift+Left) 
 Windows(Shift+Alt+Left)  
**Move selected tab(s) Right**: 
 Mac(Ctrl+Shift+Right)  Windows(Shift+Alt+Right)  
**Move selected tab(s) to the Left-most Position**:  Mac(Ctrl+Shift+Down)  Windows(Shift+Alt+Down)  
**Move selected tab(s) to the Right-most Position**:  Mac(Ctrl+Shift+Up)  Windows(Shift+Alt+Up)  
The shortcuts can be customized from chrome://extensions/shortcuts

Comment: @AndrewM But that solution only works in Linux; other users still need this extension.

Comment: Seems like this is such a basic ability.  Keyboard-first development.

Comment: (on mac) I changed it using: chrome://extensions/shortcuts to: cmd-arrowkey why? because ctrl-alt-arrowkey is what i use to copy the url to the clipboard

Comment: This answer should be updated to indicate that Ctrl+Shift+PageUp/PageDown works on Windows 10 + recent versions of Chrome

Comment: @jdunning It also works on **Macs** (as of September 2023). See my comment [here](https://superuser.com/questions/629432/keyboard-shortcuts-to-arrange-chrome-tabs-on-windows/1316201#comment2834780_1316201).

Answer (score 91):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd>

Comment: Great, it works. For some reason, this is not documented by Google in their help page on Chrome shortcuts at https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en.

Comment: This only works on Linux unfortunately.  You need to use the extension linked to in the other answer for Windows and MacOS.

Comment: Works on OpenBSD's Chromium port.

Comment: Small note that this does not work while viewing a Google Docs spreadsheet. It will instead try to navigate left / right on your current spreadsheet's tabs.

Comment: worked out of the box on Ubuntu Linux 20.04 LTS (PopOS)

Comment: Works on my Windows 10 OS.

Comment: Works for me in Windows 10 and Chrome Version 112.0.5615.121 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Works for me in macOS too, yay!

Comment: Checked on **macOS** Ventura (13.5.1) and the latest version of Chrome (116.0.5845.140) - it works! To use this shortcut with a keyboard that doesn't have dedicated PgUp/PgDown keys (e.g. MacBook Pro, compact keyboards etc), use the `Fn` button with arrows Up/Down to emulate PgUp/PgDown keys. So the whole combination will be as follows: Ctrl+Shift+Fn+Up/Down.

Answer (score 39):

If you don't want to use extensions, you can focus tabs using

- <kbd>F6</kbd>, <kbd>F6</kbd>

Now you're in tab-selection mode, and can use the keyboard for a variety of tab-editing tasks.

- Move cursor: <kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd>
- Move tabs: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>
- Move to the beginning or end: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>
- <kbd>Enter</kbd> focuses the page.

This also works very nicely with tab groups:

- Create new groups by pressing <kbd>Menu</kbd>,<kbd>Down</kbd>,<kbd>Right</kbd>,<kbd>Enter</kbd>,<kbd>Name of group</kbd>,<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- You can move tabs into groups with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd>
- Expand or fold group by moving the cursor to the group label and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Change group settings by pressing <kbd>Menu</kbd>

I currently don't know of a way to select multiple tabs.

If you are remapping these shortcuts using AutoHotKey or macros, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to focus tabs, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>F6</kbd> to focus the page. These shortcuts work from anywhere, regardless of what is currently focused.

Comment: Great, Windows solution without need for extensions. I vote to make this the **accepted answer**.

Comment: this is the only correct answer here

Comment: Nice! I didn't know you get a different focus when you press F6 twice.

Comment: Wow! Thank you.

Comment: Works on Linux as well !

Comment: Excellent! Note, when I tried it (on Windows), hitting Enter did not focus on the page. I had to hit F6 again, which worked.  (unless you have something in the status bar at the bottom, in which case just hit F6 one more time)

Comment: Okay- if you switch to another tab, hitting enter does focus. But if you just move the current tab to another position (e.g. left or right), you have to hit F6.

Comment: Sadly overflown tabs are inaccessible with this method, it only works on tabs visible in the tab-bar.

Comment: @LJ_1102 A workaround is to either move some tabs into a group so the overflown tabs get visible, or to create a new window, although it sounds like you might need a tab organising extension such as https://www.one-tab.com/

Answer (score 6):

No need to dedicate a whole extension just for this. The [AutoControl shortcut manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocontrol/lkaihdpfpifdlgoapbfocpmekbokmcfd) for Chrome can do this easily.

For example, you can use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to move a tab to the left and right, as shown in the following screenshot:
[image]
You could also use the scroll wheel instead of the arrow keys, as I do. You have lots of possibilities.

Comment: GREAT recommendation to eliminate one of the many quirks that make Chrome much inferior to Waterfox (IMHO). However, I still need to find why Shift is stolen from the whole Chrome system, if used with the shortcut. :-(

Comment: @CharlesRobertoCanato, What do you mean by "stolen"? You mean you found a bug?

Comment: Sorry for my poor English, @Mercalli. Yeah, there was some situation after I built my move tabs shortcut where Shift was not being recognized by any Chrome tab or window. However, I could not reproduce it. I deleted the shortcut and built it again, and all has worked as expected.
Anyway, I remembered that Vimium also offers this specific feature, so for now I went back to it. But it was a great tip, really.

Comment: @CharlesRobertoCanato, I tried vimium as well but it had too many restrictions. It doesn't work on extension tabs or `chrome://` tabs or error pages or Web Store tabs and so and so on. It also can't customize existing shortcuts. It's not a reliable shortcut extension in general. AutoControl doesn't have any of those problems.

Comment: Oh, I apologize I wasn't very clear - my fault, sorry @Mercalli - I went a bit off-topic. AutoControl felt like a great extension for customizing the *browser* itself, and does it very nicely, the action creation is great. Vimium is not restricted: it's great on customizing the *browsing* (where AutoControl is only reasonable), but that's just *my* use case (very rarely I need anything from chrome or store pages). However, AutoControl is still a *great* answer to the OP.

Answer (score 6):

With [Vimium C](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium-c-all-by-keyboard/hfjbmagddngcpeloejdejnfgbamkjaeg?hl=en) extension you can move tabs to left or right using the `<<` (`Shift + ,,`) or `>>` (`Shift + ..`) keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: https://github.com/gdh1995/vimium-c/issues/368 for customizing the shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

This extension does exactly that. Move tabs around with

CTRL+SHIFT+LEFT & CTRL+SHIFT+RIGHT

No frills.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/move-tab/lioifkjmgeijapfaccompfkdhbodcpkd/related

Just one problem CTRL+SHIFT+LEFT is used for text selection : ) in an input box or text area.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Zikoat's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1609429/1180168), on a Mac, you can focus tabs by pressing `Cmd`+`opt`+`Up`/`Down` keys (`F6` couldn't do if for me).

- Move tab to the beginning or the end: `Cmd`+`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Left`/`Right`

**Ps:** I don't have enough reputation to comment on the said [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1609429/1180168), that's why I had to add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another helpfull Chrome extension: [Shortkeys (Custom Keyboard Shortcuts)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck)